# How do I use Gnome's sudo dialog from perl?

Tags: perl, gtk, sudo, gtk2

I need to run a privilegied command on a gtk2-perl user program. I'm googling about how to use the default dialog for getting root privilegies on Gnome, but can find an answer.

The only approach I have is to ask the password and use in a command

```
"echo $passwod | sudo -S priv-command"
```

but it's a bit ugly. I'm looked for the old gtksudo and similar helper programs but seems that there aren't in Ubuntu 10.10

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not gtksudo, but `GKSu` is the name. The same thing in KDE is called `kdesu`.

The dialog you are talking of is from `PolicyKit`.